Let $ 0 \to M \to M' \to M'' \to 0 $ be a short exact sequence of $R$-modules. If $M$ and $M''$ are torsion free, then $M'$ is torsion free.
Assume $R$ be a domain and $M,M'$ and $M''$ are $R$-module.
Let $ 0 \to M \to^{\varphi} M' \to^{\phi} M'' \to 0 $
be a short exact sequence of $R$-modules. If $M$ and $M''$ are torsion free, then $M'$ is torsion free.
Definition: Let $R$ be a domain. Let $M$ be an $R$-module. We say an element $m \in M$ is torsion if there exists a nonzero $r \in R$ such that $rm = 0$. In particular, $M$ is called torsion free if the only torsion element of $M$ is $0$. Of course, if $R$ is a integral domain then $M$ becomes automatically torsion-free.
Now, Let $m' \in M'$ be a torsion element, which means there exists a nonzero $r\in R$ such that $rm'=0$.
Consider, $\phi(rm')=r\phi(m')=0 \implies \phi(m')=0 \implies m'\in \ker(\phi)=\text{Im}(\varphi)$. Hence there exist $m\in M$ such that $\varphi(m)=m'$
I stucked here, what I need to do? Thanks

Then $\varphi(rm) = rm' = 0$, which implies that $rm=0$ since $\varphi$ is injective.
Hence, as $M$ is torsion free, $m=0$, and then $m'=0$.

Seems pretty clear, how did I miss that! Thanks

Alternative proof: Recall that a module over a commutative ring $R$ is torsionfree when for every regular element $ r \in R$ the map $r : M \to M$ is injective, i.e. that the kernel $\ker(r : M \to M) = \mathrm{Ann}_M(r)$ is trivial.
Now, the exact sequence $0 \to M \to M' \to M'' \to 0$ yields for every $r \in R$ the commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> M @>>> M' @>>> M'' @>>> 0 \\
@. @VV{r}V  @VV{r}V @VV{r}V @.\\
0 @>>> M @>>> M' @>>> M'' @>>> 0
\end{CD}$$
with exact rows. Hence, the snake lemma yields in particular an exact sequence
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Ann}_M(r) @>>> \mathrm{Ann}_{M'}(r) @>>> \mathrm{Ann}_{M''}(r).
\end{CD}$$
Thus, if $M$ and $M''$ are torsionfree, $M'$ is torsionfree as well.

Since it is a short exact sequence, you have that $\varphi$ is injective.
Now, $\varphi(rm)=r\varphi(m)=rm'=0$, and by injectivity and torsion-freeness of $M$ you have that $m=0$, so $m'=0$ and you have the contradiction.
